# Hibernate criteria : Distinct and orderby

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, hibernate-criteria

How to select column from oracle in criteria query using both distinct and order by. I am able to use either distinct or order by which works,but not able to use both of them at a time.
The problem i am facing in criteria , distinct for one column and i have to order the results based on another column in the same table.

```
Criteria cr = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(example.class);
cr.add(Restrictions.eq("quote", quote));
cr.add(Restrictions.eq("optn", optn));
cr.add(Restrictions.eq("prdct",prod));
//Adding distinct to show only distinct messages,
ProjectionList projection = Projections.projectionList();
projection.add(Projections.distinct(Projections.property(("Message"))),"Message");
projection.add(Projections.property("screenNo"),"screenNo");
cr.setProjection(projection);
cr.addOrder(Order.asc("screenNo"));

cr.setResultTransformer(new AliasToBeanResultTransformer(example.class));
resultList=cr.list();
```

example table

```
quote |S option |S  message  |S               screenNo
1123  |S 11 |S    This screen is about policy |S      100
2222  |S 22 |S    This screen is about loss |S      103
3333  |S 33   |S  This screen is about term |S       102
4444  |S 44 |S    This screen is about policy    |S   101
```

Comment: Please show a small dataset and what you have tried already.

Comment: This line `cr.setResultTransformer(new AliasToBeanResultTransformer(example.class));` is not neccesary.